# Speech to text, java speech API, where to find it?

Tags: java, api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I wanted to create a small application for my laboratory at home, and I need speech recognition so the java speech API seems as a pretty good solution to my problem of finding a suitable API. I have tried the Sphinx-4 API but I couldn't find any JAR-files in the PreAlpha.zip package that I downloaded, I could only find header files for C projects... I also looked into the Freetts API but that's only text to speech and not the other way around!

So if anyone can find the Java speech API I would be glad if you could send me the download link and not just a link to oracle's webpage because I have given this some amount of time and still I have not found the download link to the bin/lib folder full of JAR-files...

Thanks for any help! Please excuse my English, comment a question if you don't understand any part of it! :)

Comment: Keep in mind that I have given it a few searches on google, I could only find documentation and tutorials on how to use it but not the path to the download link if I did not made this clear enough! :)

Comment: There an explanation on how to use the `jar`s on the Sphinx-4 tutorial : You can also use Sphinx4 in non-maven project, in that case you need to download jars from the repository manually together with dependencies (which we try to keep small) and include them into your project. You need sphinx4-core jar and sphinx4-data jar if you are going to use US English acoustic model. For further reference: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Comment: Could you post the link here to the repository? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the link: https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~ which you can also find in the tutorial page I linked.

Comment: Sorry to ask this many questions... But which repository is it? I searched for sphinx for it gave me a lot of samples and not a single main repository.

Comment: Showing 0 records when I try your search;quick link if that's what you meant

Comment: Use artifact search on the left side you must find results I this link I already search for `sphinx` https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: jars]

Search for sphinx and pick the `jars` in `sphinx4-data` and `sphinx4-core`. I have added a screen for clarification. On the right bottom select the artifact tab instead of maven for a download button.

Comment: Yeh I finally figured it out just like that! Thank you, I have the Jars in my project now, but I do get an error, I'm trying to follow the tutorial that you linked me to! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can download sphinx via sourceforge repository. To download go to this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4
After that you can choose either [5prealpha](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5prealpha/) or the beta versions like [1.0 beta6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta6/)
and download them in zip format.For 1.0 beta6 you can choose either the sphinx4-1.0beta6-src.zip or the sphinx4-1.0beta6-bin.zip

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried the prealpha package but I didn't know how to include that in my java projects.

Comment: hey @Darawan I think this video will help you to set up sphinx in java https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSnjlmfkrG0

Comment: Thank you, I think this will help! :)